# How to speed up this code when converting float to string?

Tags: c++, performance

I have profiled my unit test and the majority of the time the application is running is spent on this section of code. It is a function that converts a float to a string. How can I rewrite the code below to have a better speed performance?

Am I misreading the report and the bottleneck is somewhere else?

The profile reports states:

> Total CPU % = 13.02% , Self CPU % .07, Total CPU(ms) 769, Self CPU out
>   of 100 percent 769 ms.

769 out of 5907 samples.

```
std::string FloatToScientificString(float val, int width, int precision)
{
    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << std::scientific << std::setw(width) << std::setprecision(precision) << std::setfill(' ') << val;
    return buffer.str();
}
```

Comment: I guess the formatting shall stay identical when tweaking the current solution?

Comment: Converting float to string is a complex operation, and the C++ stream formatter is not a specially light piece of code. Maybe you could try whether the C formatter (`sprintf(buf, "%*.*e", width, precision, val)`) would be quicker.

Comment: Also, do you really need to convert it to a string?  What are you doing with that string once you have it?

Comment: i need to verify that packets sent through the serial comms are correct. they are represented as std::vector<char>.

Comment: "I have profiled my unit test" - why?  Is running the unit test taking an excessive amount of time?  If not, don't worry about it.

Comment: Do you control the protocol? Can you add a checksum? Or perhaps use other verification of the packets? This really depends on the protocol you use for the packets, and of course the serial hardware (RS232 vs. RS485 for example, and cable lengths, and more).

Comment: So this piece of code takes a lot of time in unit test which only runs this test? Isn't that to be expected? What % of time does it take with real data coming from network?

Comment: Regarding the unit tests, the tests themselves should not be profiled or disregarded from profile reports. They are really irrelevant for the performance of the final application. You also need to profile and measure *optimized* builds of the main code, since that's (hopefully) what will be sent out.

Comment: my problem is that running all the tests take 500 seconds to run which is getting ridiculous. I don't want to wait 500 seconds every time i build.

Comment: @rafaelgonzalez -- 500 seconds for unit tests is, indeed, a problem. Just guessing, though, the serial communication itself is going to take much more wall clock time than converting received values to text. If this can't be avoided, I'd consider running a subset of the tests, and now and then the full tests.

Comment: Then you should consider using something like *continuous integration* and supporting tools like remote build servers. Consider something like [travis-ci.org](https://travis-ci.org/) which can help you automate builds and tests and even create deployable packages. Unit tests doesn't need to be run each and every time you just build your project, or even not for every commit to your source-code repository. Once a day might be enough.

Comment: Your UNIT TESTS are taking 500 seconds to run?  My project has several hundred thousand source files, containing hundreds of megabytes of code, with 72% unit test coverage, and takes under 2 seconds to run.  And we think that's a serious problem for taking so long and are trying to reduce the unit test run time overhead.

Comment: Found the main bottleneck, I keep regenerating the files at every setup and it calls the float to string function over and over. I moved the file generators to global scope, and now each test runs at 7ms. Total time for all the tests now is  only 3.5 seconds. I will still try to compare the speed difference between fmtlib and stringstream out of curiosity.

Comment: @Eljay I wouldn't go so far as to accuse you of bragging, but a unit test by definition only has to be rerun when the corresponding component changed (in practice, not all dependencies can be reasonably faked/mocked away though). If 2s (for running all test suites?) is seriously too much, it therefore means you are changing all of your components all the time, or you're running the UT way more often than actually needed. I'd wager a guess here… back on topic, the slowness of `iostream` is compounded here by creating a new stream every time and not reusing allocations.

Comment: @ArneVogel • Yes, 2 seconds for the entire unit test suite.  The entire integration and system test suite took significantly longer to run (over 600 hours).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If using an external library to achieve this goal is possible, you can go with [fmtlib](http://fmtlib.net/latest/index.html) (this library will probably make it into the standard), which claims to be faster than other approaches (see their [benchmarks](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt#benchmarks)).

```
#include <fmt/format.h>

std::string FloatToScientificString(float val, int width, int precision)
{
    return fmt::format("{:>{}.{}e}", val, width, precision);
}
```

This should return an identical string as your original function, and you don't sacrifice type safety as with `std::*printf` approaches. When using [abseil](https://abseil.io/) instead (they claim to be notably faster than the `printf`-family [here](https://abseil.io/blog/20180622-format)), the function looks like this:

```
#include <absl/strings/str_format.h>

std::string FloatToScientificString(float val, int width, int precision)
{
    return absl::StrFormat("%*.*e", width, precision, val);
}
```

There is also [boost format](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/format/), which does not allow for width or precision specifier to be passed as arguments, but this works equally well:

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>

std::string FloatToScientificString(float val, int width, int precision)
{
    const std::string fmt = "%" + std::to_string(width) + "." +
        std::to_string(precision) + "e";

    return boost::str(boost::format(fmt) % val);
}
```

and finally, without any external dependencies other than the standard library (note that using `std::snprintf` is superior to `std::sprintf` as the buffer size is checked, but neither function is type safe):

```
#include <cstdio>

std::string FloatToScientificString(float val, int width, int precision)
{
    static const int bufSize = 100;
    static char buffer[bufSize];

    std::snprintf(buffer, bufSize, "%*.*e", width, precision, val);

    return std::string(buffer);
}
```

A correct performance analysis of these options is probably a topic on its own. Any of these options should be notably faster than the original approach using `std::stringstream`, though, and all snippets except the `std::snprintf` one are type safe.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl It's based on pythons `string::format`; Horrible or not it's already widely in use in practice. For simple use case the syntax is quite simple.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of converting the incomming data from float to a char representation, you should try to generate your comparison data to the incoming binary format, maybe only once with a tool which creates a compilable binary table.

This enables you to compare binary/float against binary/float data without any need to do further coversions during runtime.

And also you can do your tests ones, record the incomming data to some storage and compare later against that storage again. So you only once compare your string representation and later on you compare against the binary stored data. This can be done as long your testcases stay untouched.